# Pinning Elements with Debounced Scroll Event for Performance

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, scroll, debouncing

What is the right way to smoothly pin an element according to scroll position?
I tried debouncing a scroll listener for performance but the pinning is not accurate. Even with debouncing set to 10ms it's not smooth and the element doesn't snap cleanly to its initial position.

```
var scrolling = false;
var stickPosY = 100;
var heights = [];

$(".element").each( function(index) {
  heights[index] = $(".element[data-trigger=" + index + "]").offset().top;
});

function pin() {
  if ( !$("#aside").hasClass("fixed") ) {

    var stickyLeft = $("#aside").offset().left;
    var stickyWidth = $("#aside").outerWidth();
    var stickyTop = $("#aside").offset().top - stickPosY;

    $("#aside").addClass("fixed"); 
    $("#aside").css({"left": stickyLeft, "top": stickyTop, "width": stickyWidth});
  }
}

function unpin() {
  $("#aside").css({"left": "", "top": "", "width": ""});
  $("#aside").removeClass("fixed")
}

$( window ).scroll( function() {
  scrolling = true;
});

setInterval( function() {
  if ( scrolling ) {
    scrolling = false;

    var y = window.scrollY;
    console.log(y);

    // PIN SIDEBAR
    y > stickPosY ? pin() : unpin();

    //TRIGGERS
    for (var i=0; i < heights.length; i++) {  
      if (y >= heights[i]) {
        $('.element[data-trigger="' + i + '"]').addClass("blue");
      }
      else {
        $('.element[data-trigger="' + i + '"]').removeClass("blue");
      }
    }
  }
}, 250 );
```

Here's my [Pen](https://codepen.io/Flothus/pen/bGbqdGQ?editors=1111)

I tried to use scrollMagic for the project on a scene with a pin and additional triggers but the scrolling wasn't very smooth. So I'm trying to rebuild it with a stripped-down version and debounced listeners. Is this approach possible, or should I rather try to optimize my scrollMagic scene?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As James points out, you can just use `position: sticky` as one option, but that doesn't work in older browsers and its uses are limited to simpler situations in newer browsers, so I'll continue with the JS solution assuming you want to go that route.

There is a lot going on in your JS, and I think you are probably overcomplicating things, so I will give you a few basics to consider.

1. When you are toggling things based on scroll, either toggle inline styles or a class, but not both. I would recommend toggling a class because it allows you to have one function that can work on multiple screen sizes (i.e., you can use media queries to change the behavior of your toggled class based on screen size). Also it keeps all your styles in one place instead of having them split between your JS and your stylesheet.
2. Try to keep the work you're doing while scrolling as minimal as possible. For example, cache references to elements in variables outside your scroll function so you're not continually looking them up every time you scroll a pixel. Avoid loops inside scroll functions.
3. Using `setInterval` is not generally the recommended approach for increasing performance on scroll functions. All that is going to do is run a function every X amount of time, all the time, whether you're scrolling or not. What you really want to do is rate-limit your scroll function directly. That way, if you scroll a long ways real fast your function will only be called a fraction of the total times it would otherwise be called, but if you scroll a short distance slowly it will still be called a minimum number of times to keep things looking smooth, and if you don't scroll at all then you're not calling your function at all. Also, you probably want to **throttle** your function in this case, not debounce it.
4. Consider using the throttle function from Underscore.js or Lodash.js instead of inventing your own because those ones are highly performant and guaranteed to work across a wide variety of browsers.

Here is a simple example of sticking an element to the top of the screen on scroll, throttled with Lodash. I'm using a 25ms throttle, which is about the maximum amount I'd recommend for keeping things looking smooth where you won't really notice the delay in the element sticking/unsticking as you scroll past your threshold. You could go down to as little as 10ms.

```js
$(function() {
  $(window).on('scroll', _.throttle(toggleClass, 25));

  const myThing = $('#my-thing');
  const threshold = $('#dummy-1').height();

  function toggleClass() {
    const y = window.scrollY;
    if (y > threshold) {
      myThing.addClass('stuck')
    } else {
      myThing.removeClass('stuck');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
#dummy-1 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: steelblue;
}
#dummy-2 {
  height: 150px;
  background-color: gold;
}
#my-thing {
  width: 300px;
  height: 75px;
  background-color: firebrick;
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 0;
}
#my-thing.stuck {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}
body {
  margin: 0;
  height: 2000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.0.0/lodash.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="dummy-1"></div>
<div id="dummy-2"></div>
<div id="my-thing"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. Noticed even with the throttle set to 25ms there is a tiny jump on fast scrolling. 

Really curious how this should be done, limiting the scroll event seems necessary but for pinning it doesn't really work because it's unprecise. I feel like the best would be to reduce the throttling in the range of the trigger but that sounds over-complicated again.

The reason there is going on so much in the js is I'm trying to get this jank free https://demo.floriangrohmann.de/en/services

Comment: @flobb in my experience the small blip with fast scrolling is basically unavoidable. You could take your throttle down to 10ms, but ultimately there is always going to be that tradeoff of looks vs performance; that's just the cost of doing business here. In reality users are unlikely to even notice. The tiny blip you can see in this demo is as bad as it's ever going to get because I purposely used bright, contrasting colors that line up perfectly to demonstrate the effect. In your demo site, though, there's not such a clear line, so people probably won't even notice a problem.

Comment: Btw one tip I would give you to increase performance of your transitions is to avoid using the `all` keyword and instead only transition what you really want to. I didn't dig into your code on your demo site much, but that's just one thing I noticed off the bat. You can comma-separate transitions if you want to transition multiple properties on the same element, for example `transition: height 300ms ease, opacity 300ms ease`.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea will try that. Will it make a difference if I set up a listener with little throttle for the pinning and a second listener for adding the transition classes? Or would I just add a less expansive listener to an expansive listener? BTW Are there any introductory lessons for this kind of stuff? :-))

Comment: @flobb I would recommend trying to avoid having several different scroll listeners, but one minimally throttled one and another more significantly throttled one could work if you want. I would recommend testing it out and trying to honestly assess if you can notice any difference in the smoothness. The best thing you can do for performance is to make the operations happening inside the scroll function as simple as possible – as few variables as possible, and just one or two instances of "is x > y?", basically – and then keep everything else in separate functions.

Comment: Those other functions may or may not have extra logic in them to make sure they're not called more often than they need to be. Also this isn't a topic I can remember really having read a specific guide about, so I don't have anything in particular to point you to, but looks like if you just google for "throttling introduction javascript" there are several articles on the first page that could be good to read through.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'm experiencing first improvements with your tips. Hope I can read more about it

Comment: Can someone explain why we use throttle here over debounce?

Comment: @OksanaRomaniv if we used debounce and then scrolled a long ways down the page, the header would never snap into place until we stopped scrolling, instead of smoothly attaching to the top of the screen as we scrolled by. Try Googling for "javascript debounce vs throttle." There are numerous articles on this topic so you can learn more.

Answer (score 0):

You could try [fixed or sticky CSS positioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position#Fixed_positioning):

```css
#element {
  position: fixed;
  top: 80px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

Position: fixed would keep the element always at 80px from the top and 10px from the left edge regardless of scroll position.

```css
  #element{
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
  }
```

This is from a project of mine.  The element is a nav bar.  It sits below a header bar, so when you are at the top of the page, you see the header then the nav below it, and as you scroll down, the header moves off screen but the nav sticks at the top and is always visible.

Comment: It is using ```postition:fixed```, but debouncing causes a jump if you don't scroll ridiculously slow. It's fine without debouncing but tricky with performance. On a more complex site /w video + additional triggers on scroll it janks :(